# Using conditional while loop until getting all API requests a result python

Tags: api, while-loop, python-requests, pandarallel

I am using pandarallel and requests to get results from a website but its responses to my API doesn't cover my whole request. So I want to do a while loop that takes unanswered rows nder to_doDf and sends requests to API for to_doDf while deleting rows from to_doDf and as I get responses from API. The basic logic is that while there are empty rows under results columns unless length of it is zero send a request to API until it receives an answer. But I can't write the code to delete the rows of answered API's.

```
doneDf = pd.DataFrame()
to_doDf = macmapDf_concat[macmapDf_concat['results'].isna()]
while len(to_doDf) != 0:
  doneDf['results'] = to_doDf.parallel_apply(lambda x: 
requests.get(f'https://www.macmap.org/api/results/customduties?reporter= 
{x["destination"]}&partner={x["source"]}&product={x["hs10"]}').json(), 
axis=1)
doneDf
```

Comment: Hey I edited to add the missing parts of my code that I removed. you can think of macmapDf_concat as concat output of another dataframe I had and the results I gathered from the API request.

Comment: Here's a general tip. Make a dataframe that contains the "to do" (initially everything). Let the loop until the "to do" is empty (you don't need a `validity_check` flag at all). Inside the loop, keep subtracting the successful records from the "to do", and adding them to a "done". This way you only need to call `requests.get()` in one place (in the loop) and your code gets a lot simpler.

Comment: Hello Tomalak, your comment was very helpful thank you! Like you suggested I gathered the rows that did not get a response from API into to_doDf. But I am having trouble deleting the rows from the to do dataframe inside the loop. So I edited my code above

Comment: If there is a way to concat rows into a dataframe, there must be a way to subtract rows from a dataframe. I am no Pandas user, so I don't know how that exactly works off the top of my head, so I can't write the line of code that does it. Also I don't feel like looking it up in the documentation, but I'm sure a "subtraction"/"difference" operation is possible in Pandas.